# ASP.NET Parser error only on server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm getting the common YSOD Parser error as shown below:

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Parser Error 
 Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

 Parser Error Message: Could not load type '_3rd_party_data_reporting_tool.edtk'.

 Source Error: 

 Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="edtk.aspx.vb" Inherits="_3rd_party_data_reporting_tool.edtk" %>
 Line 2:  
 Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 Source File: /gpo/edtk.aspx    Line: 1

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3082; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082
```

The thing is I only get the error after I've published it to a target webserver. It runs fine in localhost and it runs fine if I publish it to the IIS on my machine and run it from there. Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: Is ASP.NET setup correctly on the server?

Comment: Looks like the `'_3rd_party_data_reporting_tool.edtk'` runtime is not installed on the server.